# KeyError:True when using get_loc with boolean values

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

So I have this dataFrame where each value is a boolean value.
I am trying to use `index.get_loc` with the dataFrame to get locations of cells matching True.

```py
df.index.get_loc(True)
df.index.get_loc(np.bool_(True))
```

Both of these lines are giving `KeyError : True`.
I understood why the first line of code would be giving the error as the datatype of dataFrame is not a python boolean object but a numpy boolean object (`'class <numpy.bool_>'`) as I had checked using the `type()` function.

So is there any way to use get_loc to do what I am asing for ?

Here is a column of my dataFrame, others also similiar like this.

```
0      False
2      False
3       True
4      False
5      False
       ...  
762     True
763    False
```

Comment: The boolean type has nothing to do with this.  There aren't any boolean values in your `df.index`.  It's just integers or a `range`.

Answer (score 0):

As Dataframe output shown by you, it looks like an index of your Dataframe ranges from 0 to 763 hence you are getting **KeyError** and I think you will need to first set the index of the Dataframe as a column which is having **True** and **False** values.

Comment: Hi ! It was actually just a column of my dataFrame, the reason of KeyError is beacuse it can't differentiate b/w the boolean value in the dataFrame and the boolean value object we got in numpy and python.

Answer (score 0):

Make a series with some boolean values:

```
In [2]: s = pd.Series([True, False, True])
In [3]: s
Out[3]: 
0     True
1    False
2     True
dtype: bool
In [4]: s.index
Out[4]: RangeIndex(start=0, stop=3, step=1)

In [6]: s.index.get_loc(True)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<ipython-input-6-269434a6ba3e>", line 1, in <module>
    s.index.get_loc(True)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pandas/core/indexes/range.py", line 349, in get_loc
    raise KeyError(key)
KeyError: True
```

What's `get_loc` do?

> Get integer location, slice or boolean mask for requested label.

So if we make the Series with a more interesting index:

```
In [10]: s = pd.Series([True, False, True],index=list('abc'))
In [11]: s
Out[11]: 
a     True
b    False
c     True
dtype: bool
In [12]: s.index.get_loc('b')
Out[12]: 1
```

So both from the docs and testing, we see the `get_loc` cannot be used to find particular values in the Series.  It finds values in the Series.index.  That's a very different thing.